# Program crashes after fscanf() encounters EOF

Tags: c, file-io, file-handling, eof, scanf

I'm not even sure if fscanf() actually encounters EOF. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i=0,a[13];
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
}
else
{
    i=0;
    while((fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i]))!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",i);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Test input is:

> 12
> 32
> 45
> 65
> 92
> -1
> 0
> 61
> 15
> 13
> 12
> 24
> 0
> 4

I'm running it in code-blocks.

[This is the runtime condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbvCA.jpg)

Comment: Please add more detail about your problem

Comment: Maybeunrelated, but your program is likely to crash if `fopen` returns NULL, because in that case you should not call `fclose`. And it will also most likely crash if there are more than 13 integers in your file.

Comment: `while((fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i]))!=EOF && i < 13){…}`

Answer (score 4):

It's not about `fsanf()` returning `EOF`, rather, before that itself,, by providing a *longer* input sequence, you're overrunning the destination array `a`. Attempt to access out of bound memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Result can be *anything*.

When you already have a fixed-length array, don't *allow* arbitrary number of inputs to be stored, limit the index by the array size (`arraysize-1`).

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: @SagarmayBiswas You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Answer (score 0):

Your input has 14 elements which you try to read into 13 element array `a[13]`. That is why you have a crash.
Increase the size of the array or protect the array from overflow. For example

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 14

int main()
{
  int i;
  int a[ARR_SIZE];
  FILE *fp;

  fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
  if(fp==NULL)
  {
     printf("File open error\n");
  }
 else
 {
      i=0;
      while ( (i<ARR_SIZE) && (fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i]))!=EOF)
      {
         printf("%d\n",a[i]);
         i++;
      }

   printf("%d",i);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```